# Twitter, is he following me or not?

Tags: twitter

Someone who I am neither following nor is following me appeared on my home page on twitter, why?

Comment: Post the screenshot. It's probably a retweet

Answer (score 5):

He is followed by someone who you follow, and his tweet was *retweeted* by the person you follow. That's why his tweet appeared on your timeline. For more about retweeting, you may see [this page](http://support.twitter.com/entries/77606-what-is-retweet-rt).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to one of your friends pushing the official "retweet" button, Twitter is rolling out a feature that brings ads to your feed as a normal post. [Here is an informative news article](http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-501465_162-20085467-501465.html) so you can figure out if this is happening to you. It sounds like it only happens if you're following some kind of brand, famous person associated with a brand, or spokesperson - so if you follow your 20 close friends and no one else you'll never see one. Or something. They're not very clear.